# Logging POST variables sent to a function

Tags: php, post, joomla

I am currently building a form that sends a user off to an external payment site at a certain point during the form.
At this point I have provided two URLs to the service that is providing this payment service for me, one to call the function that will update a users record at the point of pyment, and a URL that a user is directed back to after the payment process is complete.
The first URL (function call to update a users record) is "out-of-band" and will never be displayed to the user and will be from the server rather than client IP. Because of this I am in a bit of a 'blind-alley' as I cannot see the variables that are being passed back to me, and obviously these are important in order for me to parse and manipulate this data (post) in order to update our records.

I have tried writing a simple algorithm inside my function that would loop through these POST variables and write them to a text file but unfortunately I couldn't get this working (maybe something to do with Joomla?).

Here is that function:

```
public function harlandReturn() {
        $myFile = "text.txt";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
        $stringData = "";
        foreach($_POST as $i => $v) {
            $stringData .= $i . " : " . $v . " / ";             
        }
        fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        fclose($fh);
    }
```

My main question is, is there a way i can get a function to log and store any data sent to it in a file, email or something similar so I can see what they are (ints, strings, boolean, etc) and their names?

Thanks

Comment: You're doing nothing with `$stringData` ... you should use `fwrite` after the loop.

Comment: Woops sorry I pasted the wrong function. I have put the correct one there now.

Comment: What error do you get? Does the file exist? Is it empty? Are you sure you're getting the data in `$_POST` method?

Comment: The file is definitely being accessed as I have tried a 'or die('error')' on the fopen. I have also attempted to write string text to the file instead of the post variables and it doesn't seem to like this either.

Comment: So it's something about the `writing` process.
Consider @adam 's solution , add the `is_writable` condition and add an `else` statement to locate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because variables aren't always predictable - for instance, subarrays - you're probably best serializing the array and writing that to the file.

```
if(is_writable($myFile)) {
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
    $stringData = serialize($_POST);
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
}
```

You can then either open the file directly or create a quick script using `unserialize` to view it as POSTed.

Note that you're not doing any error checking to see if the file is writable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

your function is missing `fwrite()`

```
$myFile = "text.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
foreach($_POST as $i => $v) {
  $stringData = $i . " : " . $v . " / ";
  fwrite($fh, $stringData);             
}
fclose($fh);
```

or

```
$myFile = "text.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
foreach($_POST as $i => $v) {
  $stringData .= $i . " : " . $v . " / ";

}
fwrite($fh, $stringData); 
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your anwser but I had pasted the wrong function in! If you look at my edited one you can see it is the same as yours. And I have tested yours also just for sanity's sake. Nothing gets output to the text.txt file, even if I change the data from post variables to test strings.